# How to seperate toolbar and textarea in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5, ckeditor

This is my configuration
config.js:-

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
config.extraPlugins = 'newplugin';
config.toolbar = 'MyToolbar';
config.toolbar_MyToolbar =
    [
        ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Font', 'FontSize', 'TextColor', '-', 'Table','Print', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink'],
        ['Newplugin']
    ]
 };
```

This is my Default.aspx:-

```
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="editor" CustomConfig="/ckeditor/config.js" runat="server" Height="500" EnableTheming="true">
    </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
</form>
</body>
```

I want to seperate toolbar and textarea from ckeditor by using javascript , and i want to place textarea in middle of the ckeditor with 90px.

Comment: do you want this by only javascript????

Comment: using javascript or asp.net also